# how to show failure text if the loggedin user role not found ...?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, authentication, roleprovider

How to display login failure text if user logging in user role id differ than vendors role ...

i m using the following code to authenticate user role during logging in

```
Protected Sub Login3_LoggingIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles Login3.LoggingIn
        Dim user As TextBox = Me.Login3.FindControl("UserName")
        If Roles.IsUserInRole(user.Text, "Vendors") Then
            Login3.DestinationPageUrl = ("~/vendors/select_service.aspx")
        Else
            Login3.DestinationPageUrl = ("~/login.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this code was /// this will only validate the vendors role user to access teh default.aspx if i login with admin role credentials then it will not shows error ...but if i directly type ...

default.aspx then this page will be accessed by vendors and admins .... but i want only vendor user role must access the page

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, the roles purposes is not the login. login must validate credentials like username or password.

Roles in my opinion should used to determine if user have access or not to a specific section of your website/application.

to show the message, consider to add a label and change the label text property.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I wanted to authenticate the users, but if they had no roles associated with their account, cancel the login and display a message. Based on Flavio's suggestion to use a Label, this is what I came up with. (LoginInput is my LoginControl)

```
Protected Sub LoginInput_LoggingIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs)

    Dim a As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login = CType(sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login)

    LoginError.Visible = False

    If (Membership.ValidateUser(a.UserName, a.Password)) Then
        If (Roles.GetRolesForUser(a.UserName).Count = 0) Then
            LoginError.Text = "Your account does not have permission to access the system."
            LoginError.Visible = True
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```